# How to load proper data with openrowset in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Data is like below in CVS file, Loading to SQL server using openrowset. Number rows are converted fine but number with text(xy1468028906,ab1468028906) rows converted to null.

```
1468028906
1783084622
xy1468028906
AB1783084622
```

Column data type in the tabel  is `nvarchar(max)`
So, the data is loaded into table like below

```
1468028906
1783084622
null
null
```

How can we load data properly, any suggest.

Comment: Your observations would seem to be consistent with the column type actually being numeric, not nvarchar.  It seems that the non numeric data is getting nulled out.

Comment: As mentioned by Tim, this suggests a numeric destination.
It could also be related to the code page, format file or other parameters;
please share your OPENROWSET statement and table structure.